# Qt Creator / C++ - Bug that prevents use of pointers and auto-completion

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having a very serious issue with QT Creator. I can no longer use pointers to other classes and autocompletion doesn't work in my primary class. It feels like something has become corrupt, but all my code was working with a few pointers existing, then all at once none of them worked and errored out.

Line 21: `InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;` errors: `x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:21: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'` and `x:\development\inkpuppet\newdialog.h:21: error: C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Here is my **.pro file:**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = InkPuppet
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        inkpuppet.cpp \
    aboutdialog.cpp \
    inkspot.cpp \
    newdialog.cpp

HEADERS  += inkpuppet.h \
    aboutdialog.h \
    inkspot.h \
    newdialog.h

FORMS    += inkpuppet.ui \
    aboutdialog.ui \
    newdialog.ui

OTHER_FILES += \
    InkPuppet.pro.user

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc
```

Here is my default header. **inkpuppet.h**

```
#ifndef INKPUPPET_H
#define INKPUPPET_H

#include "inkspot.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class InkPuppet;
}

class InkPuppet : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit InkPuppet(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkPuppet();

    Ui::InkPuppet *ui;

private slots:
    void setMinimum(int value);
    void setMaximum(int value);
    void actionNew();
    void actionAbout();
    void testButton();
};

#endif // INKPUPPET_H
```

**newdialog.h**

```
#ifndef NEWDIALOG_H
#define NEWDIALOG_H

#include "inkspot.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class NewDialog;
}

class NewDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit NewDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~NewDialog();
    InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;

private:
    Ui::NewDialog *ui;

private slots:
    void createNew();

};

#endif // NEWDIALOG_H
```

Comment: The error does not occur in this file. It is in `newdialog.h`. Did you include `inkpuppet.h` in that file?

Comment: I did, commenting it out makes no difference. I've edited the main post with the newdialog.h code.

Comment: Replace "InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;"  with  "Ui::InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;"

Comment: Is there a chance that `inkspot.h` defines the `INKPUPPET_H` macro? so a problem with include guards? Or that you have a circular include problem, because inkspot includes newdialog?

Comment: olive - that seems to have worked, but it still doesn't make sense. I never needed to do that, why do I suddenly need to? And what's with the auto complete not working in one file?

Comment: Also; that wont be a valid solution to the problem because I am trying to create a new instance of a class passing it (this) , and it tries to convert from Ui::InkPuppet to InkPuppet.

Comment: In your case, move all your ui inclides '#include "ui_inkpuppet.h" from .h to .cpp and  follow clean->runqmake->build

Comment: Not quite sure what you're saying, if I do that then I can't use pointers in headers regardless.. clean / qmake aren't making a difference.

Comment: Ahh actually that solved the use of pointers, but I still don't have auto complete on my main file (in cpp or header).

Comment: I assume you have tried a re-start of Qt Creator and a full re-build (delete all the object files and re-compile). I have found sometimes Qt Creator/qmake can get out of sync and does not always re-compile some of the files that need to be re-compiled. I have never found where the bug lies, when things seem to wrong usually a full re-comile sorts it for me :)

Comment: Did you refactor the name of one of those classes recently? I've found that that can unintentionally corrupt the ui_inkpuppet.h file, leading to some strange behavior in autocompletion.

Comment: I haven't refactored anything. Yes I've restarted and deleted the build folder.

Comment: I still need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Replace "InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;" with "Ui::InkPuppet *pointerToPuppet;" will fix your compilation issue.
> 2. Reinstalling yourSDK may solve auto-completion issue. [Problem with Qt creator autocomplete code](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/31064)

Comment: I have auto complete in all files except one. Reinstalling wont help. And Ui::InkPuppet vs InkPuppet is an invalid solution for reasons already stated